# autocommit=true during spring transaction

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Trying to understand transactions... I'm using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and `@Transactional` annotation in a method. Although the transaction is active during the method execution (as indicated by both the logs and `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive())`, autocommit also seems to be  turned on (as shown by `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getAutoCommit())`).

I don't understand two things

- Isn't  the idea of jdbc transactions turning off autocommit and manually commiting at the end of a code block? Isn't spring transaction manager supposed to be doing something like that under the hood?
- If autocommit is really on: If one modification to the database succeeds, and a subsequent one fails, how can spring rollback the previous changes (which it does, despite the autocommit value)?

Comment: Which TransactionManager are you using? Which DataSource are you using? Note that jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection() won't return, AFAIK, the current connection, but a new one, not handled by the TransactionManager. What happens when you call getAutoCommit() on the connection passed to the callbacks of JdbcTemplate?

Comment: SimpleDriverDataSource and DataSourceTransactionManager.

Comment: Read my updated comment.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I don't know how to do that (just started reading), just wanted check if my understanding that autocommit *should* be off during a transaction is correct

Comment: Yes, it should be off, and it probably is. You typically pass a RowMapper or other kinds of callbacks to the JdbcTemplate methods. From inside of these callbacks, get the connection actually used (for example by calling resultSet.getStatement().getConnection()), and check the autocommit flag on that connection.

Comment: Thank you!! And indeed, it is off!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `doBegin()` method of the `DataSourceTransactionManager` is processed, the flag is handled.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html#doBegin(java.lang.Object,%20org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition)

If you take a look at the sources there is:

`if (con.getAutoCommit()) {
      ...
     con.setAutoCommit(false);
    }`